# Drag and drop in closed material accordion

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng2-dragula

I have an dynamic accordion inside another dynamic accordion, and I'm using `ng2-dragula` to drag and drop inside elements between accordions, so this is my accordion:

```html
<mat-accordion>
    <div *ngFor="let elem of data">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                    <span>{{elem.title}}</span>
                </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

            <div class="element">
                <mat-accordion [dragula]="'bag'"
                               [dragulaModel]='elem.childArray'>
                    <div *ngFor="let child of elem.childArray">
                        <mat-expansion-panel>
                            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                <mat-panel-title>
                                    <span>{{task.name}}</span>
                                </mat-panel-title>
                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                            <div class="child-content">
                                {{child.name}}
                            </div>
                        </mat-expansion-panel>
                    </div>
                </mat-accordion>
            </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
</mat-accordion>
```

Generated accordions will look like in this screen:

[image: Result of code above]

In this case if I try to drag items from second parent accordion to first one it wouldn't work because first parent accordion is closed. It should be opened and then drag and drop will work ok.

My question it's, can i do somehow to drag and drop elements in closed accordion, without care about opening it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're on Angular Material `6.0.0-beta.0` and above, I believe that you can use the `MatAccordion`'s `expandAll()` / `closeAll()` method

Comment: @Edric, i don't know how will help that, because i don't want to open accordion, i just want to drop element directly in closed accordion.